# How do I open this plastic surface-mounted fixture?

Tags: light-fixture

A bulb in bathroom has burnt out, and upon trying to change my bulb I've been met with a wall mount that is a bit poorly fit, and seemingly immovable. It doesn't seem to rotate, push up, or have any gap to wedge a screwdriver into and pry open. Pulling down seems to pull the whole light fixture down, but if I have to do that I'll call the landlord so I don't get blamed if I mess it up.

[image: Here's the shoddy fixture in question:]

Comment: FYI, a "flush-mount" anything results in a fixture that's level with the mounting surface _on top_, not attached to it and protruding. Ignore what marketing departments say. They're wrong.

Answer (score 4):

See the little tab in the picture? There should be one on the other side too. Bend  them outward and the dome should drop down.

[image]

Comment: I just had another try but no such luck so far - it seems like that tab is part of the white plastic at the top and doesn't want to move in any direction. I get the feeling that the bottom part might even be glued on - maybe because the mechanism had broken? I tried some WD40 and wedging a pliers in the gap for leverage but didn't have any success there either.